# Is there a way to make this reverse factorial code run more efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just starting to learn python and made a program where it calculates the factorial number based on the factorial.

For example if I give the program the number 120 it will tell me it's factorial is 5

anyways my question is how can I make this code more efficient and faster.

```
Num = int(input())
i=0

for i in range(0,Num):
  i = i + 1
  x = Num/i
  Num = x
  if (x==1):
      print(i)
```

Comment: Hint: if a factorial is recursively multiplying, then an inverse factorial is recursively what?

Comment: @wim: There is no recursion going on here.

Comment: @ScottHunter never said there was.

Comment: What if Num isn't a factorial of anything?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplications are much faster than divisions.  You should try to reach the number with a factorial instead of dividing it iteratively:

```
def unfactorial(n):
    f,i = 1,1
    while f < n:
        i += 1
        f *= i
    return i if f == n else None


unfactorial(120) # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do:

```
Num = int(input())
i=0                     # your for loop will initialize i, you don't need to do this here

for i in range(0,Num):  
  i = i + 1             # your for loop will increment i, no need to do this either
  x = Num/i             # you don't need the extra variable 'x' here
  Num = x
  if (x==1):
      print(i)
```

You can rewrite this to look something like:

```
for index in range(1, number):       # start range at 1

        number /= index              # this means; number = number / index

        if number==1:
            return index
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute the factorials in ascending order until you reach (or exceed) the factorial you are looking for, using the previous factorial to efficiently compute the next.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_factorial(num):
    i = 1
    while num > 1:
        i += 1
        num /= i
    return i

print(reverse_factorial(int(input())))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on you answer a bit more? Maybe by explaining the code?